# Proving an integral defines a norm

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I'm stuck with these question. I know how to prove the 0 condition and the scalar condition but I'm stumped out how to proceed with the triangle equality condition.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think triangle inequality is straightforward to verify, according to definition.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use that $|f(x)+g(x)|\leq|f(x)|+|g(x)|$ and that $x(2-x)\geq0$ for $x\in[0,2]$.

Comment: I know this, but wouldn't I have to prove that in and off itself?

Comment: The first inequality is just the triangle inequality of the Euclidian norm $|\cdot|$. The second one is obvious, since $0\leq x\leq2$ implies $2-x\geq0$, hence $x(2-x)\geq0$ :)